# How to add values in global Hash from method? RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some problem. I have many strings with keys and their belongings, keys are always the same. String looks like "key1=value1;key2=value2..." . So I made global Hash with arrays as values and want to store all data from strings into that hash so I made function:

```
<%
$all={}
for len in (0..$authors.length-1)
   $all[$authors[len]] = Array.new   #authors are defined and filled earlier
end

def add_hash(from)
   the_from = from.to_s.split(";")
   for one in the_from
      splitted = one.split("=")
      for j in (0..$authors.length.to_i-1)
         if($authors[j] == splitted[0])
            $all[$authors[j]] << splitted[1]
         end
      end
   end
end
%>
```

but it doesn't seem to work, is something wrong in my code? (note: I can only use Ruby on Rails code)

Comment: Define "doesn't work". You never actually *call* `add_hash`, if you were expecting it to do something. Not sure what the point of the initial hash init is, you can set a default hash value in the `Hash` constructor. Not sure why this is in what appears to be an ERB template, either.

Comment: Yes, the question is badly put. Can you give an example of the expected input and output of all variables? I don't understand what `$authors` is made of. Also, be aware that variables are not named with $ sign in ruby. You can also use `array.each_with_index { |value, index| #your code }`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for lolz)), cause of

> note: I can only use Ruby on Rails code

place it in lolo.rb in initializer folder of rails app

```
require 'singleton'

class Lolo < Hash
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    super([])
  end

  def add src
    src.to_s.split(";").each do |item|
      splitted = item.split("=")
      self[splitted[0]] = splitted[1]
    end
  end
end
```

in any place call `all =Lolo.instance` to access hash, and `all.add("key1=value1;key2=value2")` to add elements, `all.keys` is authors list

and don't use global vars cause it could cause a lot of problem

Answer (score 0):

Using global variable is a bad practice. Still if you want to use there is no problem.

In your code accessing hash variable using key as string is not allowed. So change the key to symbol by using to_sym

```
      (ie) $all[$authors[len].to_sym] similarly $all[$authors[j].to_sym]
```

This may work.